# asp.net mvc with Angular 4 allow POST from external site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular

We have a Angular 4 app using asp.net mvc. And the problem that we are having is that when an external site, in this case DIBS payment portal, tries to do a redirect back to our page using POST, we get a 404 not found.
The URL is correct and works, but now when the external site uses POST, it doesn't work.

Any ideas on how to deal with this?
In our **startup.cs** Configure method we have this :

```
 app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            await next();

            if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404
                && !Path.HasExtension(context.Request.Path.Value))
            {
                context.Request.Path = "/index.html";
                await next();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Try annotate your controller with this attribute: [IgnoreAntiforgeryTokenAttribute]

Comment: Hi, to be more precise, we are using asp.net mvc core.
The url that the external site is trying to his is not a mvc controller, it should be handled by angular, and we have a route in app.module that should handle this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by creating an api controller that handled the POST, and that returned and redirect to the requested page.

Answer (score 0):

If a resource was not found, the request should now be passed to DefaultFiles and then to StaticFiles serving index.html

Have you added this bit to your "Configure" method?

```
 app.UseDefaultFiles();
 app.UseStaticFiles();
```

Comment: Hi, I did not have  app.UseDefaultFiles();
I will check if this solves the issue, I have to push the changes to the development site first though